# How to fix table overflow to have it automatically scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have the code to allow my table to scroll when a certain height is reached. However, when I implement the code it does not change anything in the actual table. I have a attribute that changes the width, which works. Though the height and scroll attribute does not. I am not sure why it is not working.

```css
.tableScroll {
      width: 50em;
      height: 10px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-9 right-pane">
            <div class="row">
               <!--<div class="col col-md-12"> tyler mark --> 
                  <h6>General Information</h6>
                    <span class="label">*Tier:</span>
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>
                                       
                    <span class="label">Type:</span>                                  
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>
    
                    <span class="label">Name:</span>   
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text">
                    </div>
    
    
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar text-right">
                      <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Select</button>
                    </div>
    
    
                    
                      <div class="col col-md-12">      
                          <br>
                          <br> 
                          <h6>Deployment Components:</h6>  
                          <div class="table-responsive-sm">            
                          <table class="table table-sm table-hover tableScroll">                           
                            <tbody id="mytab">
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>    
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                      
                          <br>
                      </div>
      <!--</div> tyler mark-->        
            </div>
    
            
          
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">      
                    <br>
                    <br> 
                    <h6>Selection Preview</h6>                        
                    <span class="label">Query</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">SELECT * FROM WebService WHERE EXISTS (module.fileName ends-with '/1AS')</textarea>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>                      
          </div>
```

Comment: Set `overflow: auto;`

Comment: @Awais Thanks, but I tried it before and it didn't work

Comment: Can you please explain where you need scroll @kane_004

Comment: Well in that case you need to apply those properties to `.table-responsive-sm` not `.tableScroll` or move this class with `.table-responsive-sm` Post the answer below @MeghnaBhuptani

Answer (score 1):

you need to add specific height and overflow:auto; to div that wrap your table.
 for example:

```
.table-responsive-sm {
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I suggest you add a class to this div, and style with this specific class.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tableScroll {
      width: 20em;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9 right-pane">
            <div class="row">
               <!--<div class="col col-md-12"> tyler mark --> 
                  <h6>General Information</h6>
                    <span class="label">*Tier:</span>
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <span class="label">Type:</span>                                  
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <span class="label">Name:</span>   
                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar">
                      <select class="select" data-placeholder="Select...">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>                             
                        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col col-lg-12 search-bar text-right">
                      <button class=" btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Select</button>
                    </div>



                      <div class="col col-md-12">      
                          <br>
                          <br> 
                          <h6>Deployment Components:</h6>  
                          <div class="table-responsive-sm tableScroll">            
                          <table class="table table-sm table-hover ">                           
                            <tbody id="mytab">
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://IIS</td>                                
                              </tr>
                              <tr>                                 
                                <td>C://SQL</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Windows File Share</td>                         
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>C://Etc</td>
                              </tr>    
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>

                          <br>
                      </div>
      <!--</div> tyler mark-->        
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-md-12">      
                    <br>
                    <br> 
                    <h6>Selection Preview</h6>                        
                    <span class="label">Query</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3">SELECT * FROM WebService WHERE EXISTS (module.fileName ends-with '/1AS')</textarea>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>                      
          </div>
```

TRY This